# wget set name of downloaded file

Tags: wget, xml

I'm using the following command to download web pages into static html files:

```
wget --quiet http://mytestdomain.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "http?://[^<]+" | wget -i -
```

But it just outputs each file like this:

index.html

index.html.1

index.html.2

My question is, is it possible to modify this command so that each saved file uses's the original page's title instead of index.html?

Thanks

Comment: Won't that break the ability to follow links if page A has link to page B and you rename page B to something else?

Comment: Right now everything is just listed as index.html and index.html.1 and index.html.2, so that already broke the links...

Comment: Couldn't you just `wget -m` to download the XML file and all associated pages with their proper file names into the corresponding folder structure? From the man page: "-m, --mirror: Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing."

Comment: Have a look at the - - convert-links flag if I remember right that should make all the links work so you can view the site off-line and the links will all work

Answer (score 2):

option "-O filename"  will set the output name
-O is capital o, not zero